# Moving categories on top in Wikipedia

Tags: website, javascript, web, css

I've tried `Cologne Blue` theme in Preferences of Wikipedia and saw the categories bar appearing on the top of the page.

I liked the idea, but I don't want the default theme to be changed.

Is there any custom `CSS` and/or `JS` files available to replace the default location of the categories of Wikipedia articles in its default style, that is moving them from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, on Wikimedia Commons there is a gadget that does just that. Check in the js file here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-CategoryAboveAll.js

Comment: It would be better if it removed `From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia` which also appears on top along with categories, but still it is very handy already :)